# How to disable the 10 minute screen timeout/lock in KDE?

Tags: ubuntu, kde, screensaver

I'm trying KDE desktop on Ubuntu 14.04LTS (the start screen now says "kubuntu" but the DE was installed on top of regular ubuntu). When no actions have been made for like 10 or 15 minutes or so the screen locks and Spotify/youtube/anything is paused.

In `System Settings > Display and Monitor > Lock Screen`
I unchecked the timer (and put a large timeout time in the unchecked setting).

In `System Settings > Energy Saver`
i have configured it not to do anything when hooked up to AC power.

The `xscreensaver` is set to "disable screen saver"

These settings did not stop the timeout. 
I edited `~/.kde/share/config/kscreensaverrc` into:

```
[ScreenSaver]
Enabled=false
LegacySaverEnabled=false
Lock=false
PlasmaEnabled=false
Saver=krandom.desktop
Timeout=36000060
```

This had no effect. I found in another answer that doing

```
setterm blank 0
setterm powerdown 0
xset s 0 0
```

will do the trick, which it did! But it is overwritten on reboot. 
Is my only option to make this a startup script? I couldn't believe that this would be such a problem in such a standard DE...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On my version of `KDE` (4.14.12) there is a power management widget. (You can add it by right clicking on the launcher bar and choosing `Panel Options -> Add Widget`. It's called `Battery and Brightness`.) On this widget there is a checkbox labelled `Enable Power Management`. If uncheckt it disables dimming of the screen altogether. This works for me.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am on 4.13.2 and the widget here is called 'Battery Monitor'. Anyway, it had the same battery settings options (but no brightness) so i unchecked the box and we'll see if it works.

Comment: @JonatanÖström Did it work? If so it might help other users, if you mark the answer as correct.

Comment: In fact, I'm not sure. I found out that unplugging the computer changed settings and I got sick of it. I made a fresh install of kubuntu 15.04 w/ plasma 5 and in this version the regular setting for the screen lock did work.

Comment: Anyway, I marked it as correct, as it could have been an acceptable solution in case it worked, which I don't know.

Answer (score 8):

In KDE5 as of 2021-APR:

1. Open System Settings
2. Search "Screen Locking"
3. Adjust "Lock screen automatically"
   [image]

Comment: "Sreen Locking" --> "Screen Locking"

Comment: For anyone wondering, it is saved in `home/michael/.config/kscreenlockerrc`, apparently.

Answer (score 2):

## On KDE 5,

You could configure it through the `System settings`' `Screen Locking` GUI.

[image: System settings - screen locking]

What it actually does is modify `~/.config/kscreenlockerrc`, which you could also do on a terminal with the command: **`kwriteconfig5 --file ~/.config/kscreenlockerrc --group Daemon --key Autolock false`**. Removing the configuration lines under `[Daemon]` sets the corresponding settings to their default values.

```sh
[$Version]
update_info=kscreenlocker.upd:0.1-autolock

[Daemon]
Autolock=false
LockOnResume=false
Timeout=4
LockGrace=5
```

### GUI-option-to-configuration-key mappings

- `Lock screen automatically`: `Autolock`.

  - `After`: `Timeout` in minutes.
  - `After waking from sleep`: `LockOnResume`.
- `Allow unlocking without password for`: `LockGrace` in seconds.

---

### `Energy saving`

If you're also interested in configuring `System settings`' `Energy saving`, refer to https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/735124/247246.

Answer (score 1):

All,

On my Kubuntu 18.04 LTS computers the screen timeout is in the following:

"System Settings"

- "Power Management"
- "Energy Savings"
- "Screen Energy Savings"

Default is 10 minutes.  I set mine to 30 minutes.

Cheers!

OMR

Answer (score 0):

I'm using KDE Plasma 5.24.7 on a Lubuntu machine.  The setting I found is hidden in the "Power Management" widget.  To turn off the screen timeout, right click on the widget and select "Configure Energy Saving...". Then click on the left menu item "Activity Power Settings" and choose "Never turn off the screen" under the "Define a special behavior option". Hopefully that will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

In Plasma version 5.27.8

The screen locking is at `System Settings | Workspace Behaviour | Screen Locking`

[image: Plasma Scree n Locking]